# Run Promises in Sequence

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

**My Sequence is:**

- POST file to dropbox from local server
- Delete file from local server (after successful POST)
- Create a shareable link for the recently **POST**ed file
- Send User the new shareable link

*(Please note I am using the Dropbox API v2)*

**My Code:**

**I am using [request-promise-native](https://github.com/request/request-promise-native) library.**

```
let upload = (req,res) => {

let options = {
    method: 'POST',
    uri: 'https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/upload',
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer Token here',
        'Dropbox-API-Arg': "{\"path\": \"/test/"+req.file.originalname+"\",\"mode\": \"overwrite\",\"autorename\": true,\"mute\": false}",
        'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream'
    },body: fs.createReadStream(`uploads/${req.file.originalname}`)
};

rp(options)
    .then(() => {return _deleteLocalFile(req.file.originalname)})
    .then(() => {return _generateShareableLink(req.file.originalname)}) // This makes a POST request to the Dropbox API and should return a link.
    .then((shareableLink) => {sendJsonResponse(res, 200, shareableLink)})
    .catch(function (err) {sendJsonResponse(res, 500, err)});
};
```

From my understanding (**correct me if Im wrong**) promises run in parallel and return a value overtime (whichever promise resolves first). How can I run promises in a specific sequence? Is my implementation of promises within best practices?

Comment: When you chain `then`ables, they are not running in parallel

Comment: The propably worst, but the easiest approach I used is to start a new "child" promise using fetch in the `.then()` handler.

Comment: @SterlingArcher Ah I did not know that!! So when I chain promises with `then()`  they run in sequence?

Comment: Correct, because `.then` waits for a callback before executing. So a promise chain is always in sequence unless it fails. Parallel, they would all have their own calls executed outside of a resolved promise

Comment: @SterlingArcher Apologies for asking this question then. I was not aware of that fact that `.then()` run in sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your promises will work in sequence if they are used in chain.
I can suggest you also to use ES8 `async/await` features to get more beautiful code

```
let upload = async (req,res) => {

   let options = {
       method: 'POST',
       uri: 'https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/upload',
       headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer Token here',
        'Dropbox-API-Arg': "{\"path\": \"/test/"+req.file.originalname+"\",\"mode\": \"overwrite\",\"autorename\": true,\"mute\": false}",
        'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream'
       },body: fs.createReadStream(`uploads/${req.file.originalname}`)
   };

   try {
      const request = await rp(options);
      const dlf = await _deleteLocalFile(req.file.originalname);
      const shareableLink= await _generateShareableLink(req.file.originalname);
      const sendedResponse = await sendJsonResponse(res, 200, shareableLink);
   } catch(e) {
      await sendJsonResponse(res, 500, err);
   }

}
```

Comment: This is great. The code is much cleaner. I wasn't aware of the this new feature of ES8. Seems like I need to read through the ES8 features list. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: Sorry quick question. Does code within the `try` block run in sequence as well?

Comment: Yes, it works in sequence, just use `await` in front of a Promise result

Comment: Thanks. This helps a lot!